# looping over sheets with specific function in vba

Tags: vba, excel

i am very new using vba and my problem is the following: I wrote a function SCosts

```
Public Function SCosts(x As Range, y As Range) As Double

Dim n As Integer
Dim Z As Double
Dim W As Double
For n = 1 To y.Columns.Count

If (y.Cells(1, n) > 8) And (y.Cells(1, n) <> "") Then
Z = Z + 8 * x.Cells(1, n) / y.Cells(1, n)
End If

If (y.Cells(1, n) <= 8) And (y.Cells(1, n) <> "") Then
W = W + x.Cells(1, n)
End If
Next n

SCosts = Z + W
End Function
```

which works.

Now i have 20 sheets where i want to evaluate the SCosts-fct on two ranges of each sheet and then sum them up. I wrote the following ACosts function which loops over all sheets. But it does not work. Can anyone help me?

```
Public Function ACosts(t As Variant, u As Variant)

 Dim R As Variant
 Dim Z As Double
 Dim Ressource(1 To 2) As Variant

 Ressource(1) = "SHEET1"
 Ressource(2) = "SHEET2"
 ....
 Ressource(20)= "SHEET2"

 For Each R In Ressourcen
 Z = Z + SCosts(Application.Goto(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(R).Range(t)),  Application.Goto(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(R).Range(u)))
 Next R
 ACosts = Z


End Function
```

Comment: If any answer helped you, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it, for the good of the SO community.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were pretty close to getting there. I've modified some of the array and looping methods to those I prefer.

```
Public Function ACosts(t As Variant, u As Variant)
 Dim Z As Double
 Dim r As Long, Ressource As Variant

 Ressource = Array("SHEET1", "SHEET2")
 With ActiveWorkbook
    For r = LBound(Ressource) To UBound(Ressource)
       Z = Z + SCosts(.Sheets(Ressource(r)).Range(t), .Sheets(Ressource(r)).Range(u))
    Next r
 End With

 ACosts = Z
End Function
```

I tested this with the two worksheets allocated into the array. You should be able to add more worksheets with their respective names.

**EDIT:** The function should use cell addresses as strings passed into it.

`=ACosts("B15", "C15")`

An actual cell reference passed into the `ACosts` function is useless as the string value of the cell references is used on many sheets.